# Is it hazardous to leave a hole in the wall for a week or two?

Tags: repair, drywall, hole

Yesterday in a fit of manliness I accidentally punched a hole in the wall of my bedroom. I will eventually get some putty to fill in the hole but I'm concerned about the fibrous dust that may be in the air/on the walls. For a relatively small/fist sized hole is it safe to leave it exposed for a week or two? (I've simply taped over it with a swiffer duster cloth). Also I noticed my throat is slightly irritated post-wallpunch; is it possible that's due to the dust?

Come to think of it, I don't suppose it helps matters that I did pushups beside the wall after I hit it.

Comment: How old is the wall?

Comment: It might’ve been a fit but it wasn’t manliness !  Drywall dust is not hazardous to your health except in large quantities but if it’s an old house and has asbestos in the wall covering  then that’s a serious problem.

Comment: The grand-kids have done that and it was over a year before it was fixed and no one got sick.

Comment: "Over a year and no one got sick" - um, that's not how cancer works. That said, one-time exposure to rockwool isn't going to give anyone cancer.

Answer (score 2):

Breathing in the dust isn't healthy, but you've basically already created all there is to create. You should vacuum* it up and fill the hole whenever you get around to doing it. No rush.

If you patch the hole properly, you will probably create more dust patching the hole than you did in making it.

If you want to scare yourself look up the effects of breathing in silica dust.

**a shopvac with a fine particle bag or hepa filter is best for vacuuming, as drywall dust is very fine*